# Should I use caution while doing updates via Ubuntu Update manager or not?

Tags: 12.04, updates, update-manager

I am relatively new to ubuntu and wanted to know whether the updates listed in Ubuntu Update manager be done without any thoughts or should I take a look at them before installing?

There are around 630 something updates currently so taking a look at each of them individually might take a while. Do I need to?

Comment: I have never had a problem, so I would say not. With 630 updates registered, it could take some time. I update daily so that I don't get a backlog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been running Ubuntu for a great many years. I have never run into any issues with accepting the updates provided. It's what they are for...

Back before we had the updater and used Synaptic on occasion there would be a problem but this was several years ago before the automated testing proses was introduced. There is a question of completely trusting ppa's as these are out of the direct control of the Ubuntu developers. However in my years of using Ubuntu I have never run in to any issues with ppa's.

As a rule of thumb, trust your updates...

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't have anything to worry about as long as you're not using the beta version.